# Ошибка "found ..., but does not contain package" при go get

Tags: golang

Сталкивался с такой проблемой. Делаю импорт:

```
go get -u github.com/#####/bank/v2
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
go get github.com/#####/bank/v2: module github.com/#####/bank@upgrade found (v1.0.0), but does not contain package github.com/#####/bank/v2
```

`v2` есть в GitHub, но что-то не получается его импортировать. Как решить эту проблему?

P.S. `#####` - имя репо было скрыто.

Comment: У вас `v2` на какой ветке-то?

Comment: v2 как отдельная ветка идет...Кроме master-а.

Comment: А `go.mod`-то у вас там есть?  https://blog.golang.org/v2-go-modules